# Displaying custom contribution field in the online receipt

Tags: receipts, smarty

I am having trouble with displaying a custom contribution field on the online reciept.

With the offline receipt, it works great with this:

```
{crmAPI var='rname' entity='Contribution' action='getvalue' return="custom_134" id=`$formValues.contribution_id`}
{if $rname}<p>Dear {$rname},</p>{else} <p>{contact.email_greeting},</p> {/if}
```

The same code on the online receipt returns:

Dear array,

How can I fis this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smarty variables for online and offline may be different for Contribution ID.

For offline

```
{crmAPI var='rname' entity='Contribution' action='getvalue' return="custom_134" id=`$contributionID`}
{if $rname}<p>Dear {$rname},</p>{else} <p>{contact.email_greeting},</p> {/if}
```

Online

```
{crmAPI var='rname' entity='Contribution' action='getvalue' return="custom_134" id=`$contributionID`}
{if $rname}<p>Dear {$rname},</p>{else} <p>{contact.email_greeting},</p> {/if}
```

Comment: THanks, I switched the id to id=`$contributionID` and it worked